# in codeigniter facing an error as : get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter, object, ion-auth

```
Severity: Notice --> Trying to get property of non-object libraries\mongo_db.php 755
```

When using ion_auth with mongodb . Assessing collection user . it retrieves as a non-object.. any fixes ??

Comment: recast whatever array() is on line 755 to object? `(object) $array;`

Comment: mongo_db() is users table of the database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED !!** Here is the fix to avoid non-object error.
Mongo.php

```
public function __construct( $config = array(), $connect = true ) {
   if ( ! class_exists('\Mongo') ) {
       // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
       throw new \My_Exception('The MongoDB PECL extension has not been
       installed or enabled');
       // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
   }
   $this->setConfig($config, $connect);
}
```

assign `$config = array()`. So that result is always an array.